# How to test a function that changes the state of my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component:

```
// imports

class FiltersModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    status: '',
    carrier: '',
  };

  applyFilters = () => {
    const { applyFilters } = this.props;
    const {
      status,
      carrier,
    } = this.state;

    applyFilters({
      status,
      carrier,
    });
  };

  handleChange = field => ev => {
    this.setState({ [field]: ev.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { t, isFiltersModalOpened, toggleFiltersModal } = this.props;
    const { shippedDate } = this.state;

    return (
      <Modal
        open={isFiltersModalOpened}
        onRequestClose={toggleFiltersModal}
        onRequestSubmit={this.applyFilters}
      >
        <Form>

          <StatusesSelect handleStatus={this.handleChange('status')} />
          <GetAllCouriers handleCouriers={this.handleChange('carrier')} />

        </Form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

FiltersModal.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isFiltersModalOpened: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  toggleFiltersModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  applyFilters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(FiltersModal);
```

And this test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import FiltersModal from '../../FiltersModal';

jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate HoC receive the t function as a prop
  translate: () => Component => {
    Component.defaultProps = { ...Component.defaultProps, t: key => key }; // eslint-disable-line
    return Component;
  },
}));

describe('FiltersModal component test', () => {
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      t: k => k,
      isFiltersModalOpened: false,
      toggleFiltersModal: jest.fn(() => k => k),
      removeFilter: jest.fn(() => k => k),
      applyFilters: jest.fn(() => k => k),
      softlayerAccountId: '232279',
      filters: {
        carrier: 'UPS',
        shipmentId: '1234',
        shipmentType: '',
        shippedDate: '',
        shippedFrom: '',
        shippedTo: '',
        status: '',
      },
    };
  });

  it('should render without errors', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FiltersModal {...props} />);

    expect(wrapper.find('Modal')).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('Form')).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('should change state', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FiltersModal {...props} />);

    wrapper.setState({ carrier: 'UPS' });

    wrapper.instance().applyFilters();
    wrapper.instance().handleChange('status');

    expect(props.applyFilters).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(wrapper.instance().handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

What I need is to call the function `handleChange` but I am getting this error:

```
 FAIL  src/client/pages/Shipments/__tests__/components/FiltersModal-test.js
  FiltersModal component test
    ✓ should render without errors (15ms)
    ✕ should change state (12ms)

  ● FiltersModal component test › should change state

    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function anonymous]

      51 | 
      52 |     expect(props.applyFilters).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    > 53 |     expect(wrapper.instance().handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                                             ^
      54 |   });
      55 | });
      56 |
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can only use the `.toHaveBeenCalled` functions on mock functions. `handleChange` is an actual function, not a `jest.fn()` mock.

Comment: Hi @rickdenhaan even if I change that, it is not passing the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you don't need that. As well as in the real project you typically don't communicate with component's method from the outside(`ref` to call instance's methods is an exception). Instead you rely on what `render()` returns.

So I propose you to ensure that changed values go outsides through `applyFilters`:

```
it('should change state', () => {
  const applyFiltersMock = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(<FiltersModal {...props} applyFilters={applyFiltersMock} />);
  wrapper.find(StatusesSelect).props().handleStatus({ target: {value: '2'} });
  wrapper.find(GetAllCouriers ).props().handleCouriers({ target: {value: '3'} });

  wrapper.find(Modal).props().onRequestSubmit();
  expect(applyFiltersMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(applyFiltersMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({status: '2', carrier: '3'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`handleChange` is an actual function, not a mock or spy (as indicated by the error).

If you don't want to mock the function, you can use [a spy](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to check if it has been called:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "handleChange");

wrapper.instance().handleChange("status");

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check state of component by using [state](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/state.html). After triggering `handleChange` check the state of component, if state is changed to desired it should pass the test